# Formulation of a pig query with two files

Tags: apache-pig

I am stuck with a pig query. I have a data file which has a customer info and two files where the customer data could be .

data file could be

CustomerId   Age
100          27
101          17
102          25
103          21

File1 could be

CustomerId    Gender
100             M
102             F

File2 could be

CustomerId     Gender
101              F
102              M
103              M

Now, I want the output in the following fashion.If a customer Id is there in File1, then Gender should be picked from File1 . If it is not there, then it should be picked from 
File2.

So, I want the output to be

CustomerId       Age        Gender
100              27           M
101              17           F
102              25           F (picked from File1 and File1 gets the preference)
103              21           M

So, if I try to do a left outer join of data file with File1 on CustomerId, I will get NULL values for gender for CustomerId 101 and 103 . So, now I want the gender values for CustomerIds 101 and 103 to be populated from File2. I am unable to make this work . Also, do we need to do left outer join in the first place.

Comment: can we do this thing without doing UDFs likeare there any built in functions in Pig for this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you've loaded in your data like so:

```
DESCRIBE file1;
file1: {(id:int, gender:chararray)}
DESCRIBE file2;
file2: {(id:int, gender:chararray)}
```

And you join them together like:

```
joined = JOIN file1 BY id FULL OUTER, file2 BY id;
DESCRIBE joined;
joined: {(file1::id:int, file1::gender:chararray, file2::id:int, file2::gender:chararray)}
```

Giving File 1 priority while guaranteeing a non-null gender just requires a ternary operator:

```
genders =
    FOREACH joined
    GENERATE
        ((file1::id IS NOT NULL) ? file1::id : file2::id) AS id,
        ((file1::gender IS NOT NULL) ? file1::gender : file2::gender) AS gender;
```

Now you've got a single master list of genders per customer ID, and you can join this with your main data file and do with it what you like.

Comment: Thanks WinnieNcklaus . Can't we use maps here ? I was just wondering if doing a join would hamper the performance ?

Comment: If you're thinking about maps as a tool for doing lookups, then you're not really thinking like a Pig. Pig is about data flows, not algorithms. Using a `JOIN` is the Pig way to do lookups.  If your data is small enough that you could fit it all into memory as a map, then the join is not going to take a very long time. Also, in that case you can add `USING 'replicated'` so that the join doesn't require a reduce phase.

Comment: Thanks WinnieNicklaus.My idea was that join would be like O(n2) . It would be like linear scan for all the ids against all the ids of all other table. So, thats why I thought it could turn out to be an expensive operation . Meanwhile, I am imagining any operation which could call a reduce job would be an expensive operation, like Join, Group By , Order By etc. Thanks for pointing out USING replicated . Is there any disadvantage of using "replicated" though.

Comment: There's no scanning that goes on. In a standard join with a reduce phase, the records are distributed according to the join key, so they're already together at reduce time.  With `USING 'replicated'`, it basically reads it into a map, so again each lookup is O(1). There is no downside to `USING 'replicated'` if it is possible to use it. But if your data doesn't actually fit in memory your job will fail.

Comment: Ok, Winnie got it. Thanks for the explanation. If I want to add another chararray field in genders schema which signifies from which file the gender came from , can we have something like                genders =
    FOREACH joined
    GENERATE
        ((file1::id IS NOT NULL) ? file1::id : file2::id) AS id,
        ((file1::gender IS NOT NULL) ? file1::gender : file2::gender) AS gender, ((file1::id IS NOT NULL) ? "file1" : "file2") as identifier

Comment: Thanks WinnieNicklaus for the idea though.